# All developers.google.com page is displayed in mobile mode on my computer

Tags: google-chrome

When i'm go to any page of developers.google.com it shows me the mobile mode in chrome
[Sceenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppIvw.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had this problem a few times where using the track pad I have accidentally zoomed in really close to a website and it displays similarly.

Could this be the issue?